# the effect of hyperparameters in the learning process

Tags: python, training-data, hyperparameters

why do I get the same results after training even if I change only one hyperparameter?
so I decide to change more than one, but even when I change the number of iterations of training, the batch size, and the epoch_size at the same time I get the same results.

if I train my algorithm much time with different hyperparameters and it reaches the optimal results. can it change them (the training results) in the other arrivals' training?

Comment: you need to provide more details about the algorithm, the setting, the code. this is probably a bug in your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.